# Is it possible to use a copy constructor in Derived class without using Base copy constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

I am new to C++ and from what i learned until now is when we call a copy constructor from a Derived class, The copy constructor of the Base class is called. Let's say that i have a copy constructor in the private area of the Base class. How can i call the copy constructor of the Derived class without calling the copy constructor of the Base class? (In this code A doesn't have the implementation of the copy constructor and this is what i would like to know).

```
class NonCopyable
{
protected:
NonCopyable(){}
~NonCopyable(){}
private:
NonCopyable(const NonCopyable& nonCopyable);
NonCopyable& operator=(const NonCopyable& nonCopyable);
};
class A: public NonCopyable
{
};
```

Comment: No that's not possible. Copying always includes copying of the base class. You may consider having a reference member variable of `NonCOpyable` instead of deriving from it.

Comment: Technically you can. A derived type constructor is required to call *a* base type constructor. Normally, a copy constructor would call the base type's copy constructor as their goals align. But you could imaging an esoteric case where the derived type might call a different base type constructor. Though it's not possible to avoid calling *some* base constructor. Edit : Though you have to be sure that it's the right thing to do. In most cases, needing this is simply indicative of a major problem with the design you are trying to implement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you also tell me why is it necessary to implement the default copy constructor at NonCopyable class, and why might be the reason to make it Protected?

Comment: @ValeriGrishin For the same reason you make anything `protected`, you only want derived types to be allowed to do it. As to why the developer made that design decision? You should ask them. Maybe to avoid object slicing. It's not clear to use. Edit : The copy constructor is `private` here, not `protected`. So, as the name of the type implies, they just don't want you to copy a `NonCopyable` at all.

Comment: About the protected i will ask it differently. If we make the default constructor as a protected, would it prevent creating objects of type NonCopyable from someone who is not a Derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: yes, this is possible.

You only need to define a dedicated Derived copy-constructor that does *not* call the NonCopyable copy-constructor (of course this might be just confusing in a real software application, but this is a different issue):

This class is constructible, but *not* copy-constructible:

```
class CannotBeCopied: public NonCopyable {};
```

This class is constructible, and also copy-constructible:

```
class CanBeCopied: public NonCopyable {
public: 
    CanBeCopied() = default; // needed since otherwise CopyConstructor is only known construtor
    CanBeCopied(const CanBeCopied& b) { } // calls NonCopyable::NonCopyable() default-constructor, which is just protected
};
```

See life example here: 
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60c9fc42fa2dd59a

Answer (score 1):

After some search I found a way. There is a way to call a copy constructor of the Derived class without calling the copy constructor of the Base class. All what we have to do is to build the copy constructor in A, and A inherit the constructor of NonCopyable while the copy constructor is private:

```
class NonCopyable
{
protected:
    NonCopyable(){}
    ~NonCopyable(){}
private:
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable& nonCopyable);
    NonCopyable& operator=(const NonCopyable& nonCopyable);
};
class A: public NonCopyable
{
public:
    A(){}
    A(const A& other){}
};
```